# jQuery Reducing iterations in validation code

Tags: jquery, css, html, validation

I written an application that allows users to enter their personal and payment details.

I have a number of validation checks on the majority of the fields to ensure they are not blank and hope in the future to introduce other checks (e.g. numeric values only, no special characters)..

I look at my jQuery code, and it just seems i have gone about it in the long-winded way, using if else's. Here's my jQuery code using a sample of fields:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".submitForm").click(function () {

    if ($("#Firstname").val() == '') {
        $("#Firstname").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $("#Firstname").removeClass("highlight");
    }

    if ($("#Surname").val() == '') {
        $("#Surname").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $("#Surname").removeClass("highlight");
    }

    if ($("#email").val() == '') {
        $("#email").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $("#email").removeClass("highlight");
    }

    if ($("#confirmemail").val() == '') {
        $("#confirmemail").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $("#confirmemail").removeClass("highlight");
    }

    ......
    ......

    $("#PersonalDetailsRequired").removeClass("visuallyhidden ");
    //document.forms[0].submit();
});
});
```

Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Here's my jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/G3ccb/5/

Also, PersonalDetailsRequired seems to always be appear even if ALL the fields have a value in them.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Uploaded a new fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/P9eKZ/1/

What i'm trying to do is for the #PersonalDetailsRequired and #AddressDetailsRequired to only show if their respective fields are not filled in..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('form input').each(function(){
  if($(this).val()==''){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  }
});
```

---

As per your comment you can use [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/) like this:

```
$(this).not('your_selector_not_to_validate').val()==''
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense for validating every field on my page.. But there are some fields which dont require validation and can be left blank.

Comment: Thanks! Uploaded a new fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/P9eKZ/1/

What i'm trying to do is for the #PersonalDetailsRequired and #AddressDetailsRequired to only show if their respective fields are not filled in..

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use toggleClass method in jquery, instead of if/else; and each to walk through form elements like:

```
$('form input.MyCoolSelectoForValidation').each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight', ($(this).val()==''));
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G3ccb/7/

UPD: and same way you can apply to your code for displaying error msg:

```
$("#PersonalDetailsRequired").toggleClass('visuallyhidden', $('.highlight').length < 1);
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense for validating every field on my page.. But there are some fields which don't require validation and can be left blank.

Comment: than change selector to more specific

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/TFc54/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submitForm").click(function () {
        $("input").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            else 
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");       
        $("#PersonalDetailsRequired").removeClass("visuallyhidden ");
        //document.forms[0].submit();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense for validating every field on my page.. But there are some fields which don't require validation and can be left blank.

Comment: Also, PersonalDetailsRequired seems to always be appear even if ALL the fields have a value in them.

Comment: validation of the particular fields, use class name ...try http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/X6nTq/1/ ...here surname not validate.

Comment: Thanks! Uploaded a new fiddle here - jsfiddle.net/oampz/P9eKZ/1 What i'm trying to do is for the #PersonalDetailsRequired and #AddressDetailsRequired to only show if their respective fields are not filled in..

Comment: Thanks, i can understand what you have done creating new CSS classes but i was under the impression we should reuse classes wherever possible. See new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/P9eKZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way will be to use HTML5 validation, need not to add script for this:

Here are three pragmatic (but not globally perfect) examples:

Strong password:

input title="at least eight symbols containing at least one number, one    lower, and one upper letter" type="text" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required

Email address:

input type="text" title="email" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}"

Phone number:

input type="text" required pattern="(+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" title="international, national or local phone number"

Comment: this makes no sense - do you have a working example?